# kohana uri confusion

Tags: php, kohana

A route I set is not working:

```
Route::set('route_id_3', 'mod(/<action>(/<id>(:<name>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'mod',
    'action'     => 'act',
));
```

When I request ID as request parameters, I get everything set after action.
e.g. '10:name'

This happens whether it's a colon :, dash or plus +, won't matter unless it's a slash (/)

So, it only works if I replace the colon with slash => /

How can I get it to work with a - or + or colon : ?

Thank you.

ps. I want the 'name' bit to be optional. Regardless it's there or not, I need it to work. And it does, with id alone but I want it such that name being written won't affect it. Like in newspaper website's systems. Thank you!

Comment: Could you give an example of a URL you tried and the exact parameters you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by adding regular expression as third parameter in set method.

```
Route::set('route_id_3', 'mod(/<action>(/<id>(:<name>)))', array('id' => '\d+'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'mod',
    'action'     => 'act',
));
```

All digits before ':' will be 'id' and any thing after ':' will be 'name'.

So if your uri is 'mod/act/10:test'. Then your id will be 10 and name will be test.